# After upgrading from micro to small Amazon EC2 instance, I cannot deploy any new code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I upgraded from micro instance to small instance on Amazon EC2.

When I wanted to deploy a new code, the code was not deployed due to

```
** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: ELASTIC_IP (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))
connection failed for: ELASTIC_IP (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))
```

So it looks like the upgrade ignore the old elastic IP. Thus, I created a new Elastic IP and assigned this IP to the new instance and this error gone.

But when I access **www.my_project.com**, or **11.22.33.44** (elastic IP) or the Public DNS (ec2-11-222-333-444.compute-1.amazonaws.com), there is still an empty page and not my application.

The code is deployed via Capistrano without any error. On the old micro instance I used **nginx** - is this nginx accessible also on the new instance or do I need to set up/install again?

How to make my app accessible?

Thank you

Comment: How did you upgrade your instance? EBS backed instance, stop, modify and the start?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it's that the SSH key (not the EC2 key pair, but the actual SSH key coming from the machine) has changed, and by default, SSH on your local machine will block the connection for security reasons.

If you have a Mac/Linux machine you're using, you can look inside `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and remove the entry for your Elastic IP, save the changes, and try to SSH into the machine again to confirm the connection.

Not sure of the right path in Windows, but you'd make the same changes.

Comment: if it was the SSH key, the error would not be Operation timed out, but an authentication error.

Comment: If it were a Security Group issue, you'd be right. But it's an entirely separate issue if the machine's SSH fingerprint coming from the same Elastic IP has changed — which is what happens when you apply the Elastic IP to a new instance. It's neither an auth error nor a timeout. It's a preventative security measure built into SSH.

Comment: I understood the issue now, Ryan, and I've run into the problem too. It still doesn't explain why the web server responds with an empty page, but different SSH fingerprints because of new instances are a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

Aws needs manual monitoring when you end up with issues like this.
While you were upgrading your instance, what was the approach you took?

Either you

- create an ami with instance and volumes and then launch the ami with fresh small instance or
- Detach the ebs volume and attach to a small instance and made required configuration changes.

ssh into the instance and check for

- If you could manually deploy the code.
- If it's a git repo, you can pull and push changes directly.
- All the processes related to nginx,db etc are running.
- Where does the default home page for instance lands to . for ex documentroot in case of apache.conf.

I cannot rule out the possibility of key mismatch still the error doesn't points to that.